# That's an odd coin - I wonder why

Tags: geometry, real

Around the world, there are several roughly polygonal coins. Here's an example:

[image: English Coins]

One thing you'll notice is that they all have an odd number of sides. It turns out that this is universally true for modern polygonal coins (if you have an extant example where this is not true, please post it!!)

And it turns out that there's a perfectly sensible reason for this.

> Why do modern polygonal coins have an odd number of sides?

---

Edit: I've been convinced by the various answers and comments that my statement is not correct and many coins around the world are, in fact, genuine polygons. My inspiration for this puzzle (if it's really a puzzle) comes from [here](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~mathelmr/teaching/maa/tilings.pdf).

Comment: Have a look [here](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/71725.html) and [here](https://scipython.com/blog/constructing-reuleaux-polygons/)

Comment: Not an answer, but almost a contradiction: [Pieces of eight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_dollar)

Comment: Not universally true. Australian 50c piece is ten-sided.

Comment: Let me rant a bit - ALL modern coins are polygonal, because a circle is a polygon with infinite amount of edges

Comment: Israel's 5 NIS coin has 12 sides.

Comment: This seems to be a trivia question, not a puzzle...

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas what does it mean for a circle to have an infinite amount of edges? A circle's length can be expressed by a finite number... so now we are squeezing infinity into finity? That doesn't make much sense... I mean, a $\lim$ (limit) allows for infinite expressions to *approach* a finite value, but circles are kind of already drawn out, so they aren't the same cases. Therefore, I don't know how to explain that circles actually would have infinite edges, though I suppose it can be just theoretical.

Comment: @user477343 consider Zeno's paradox :) -- However a polygon is made of a *finite* amount of edges by definition, so a circle (or any curved shape) still isn't a polygon.

Comment: @Quentin oh, I remember that paradox! Like how there are infinitely many numbers between $0$ and $1$, albeit the distance between them is finite. Oh Jesus... I guess infinity does have its limits... but then again, that *is* a paradoxical assertion. Nice counter!

Comment: @Quentin, If we _choose_ such definition, then yes circle isn't a polygon, - otherwise it is, if edge amount can be infinite. Like anything - is dependent on definition, agree. Don't let to think yourself that definition is something carved in a rock. It is NOT. Because everything changes,- wikipedia, definitions and the world itself, so ...

Comment: @user477343 Math doesn't have to make sense, it's the other question which is more important - whether it **works** or not. There are series which has infinite number of terms, but still they converges to some exact number (of course not all series converges). Same holds here - circle perimeter can be expressed as a summation over an infinite series of edges. Which must converge to exact number, otherwise you will not get a perimeter and number PI :-)

Comment: The Aruban 50-cent and 5-florin coins have been four-sided since 1986.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas well-explained! I think I misconstrued this idea in a previous comment of mine. (I also love this discussion, incidentally!) :P

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this is exactly a *puzzle* (but also not sure enough to suggest closing the question or anything). Anyway, I guess the reason is that

> it's useful for them to be shapes of *constant width* (so that, e.g., they can go nicely into machines that accept coins for payment), and there's a nice simple construction for those that gives you a regular-polygon-ish shape with any *odd* number of sides; but nothing of that sort can possibly work for an even number of sides (because the diameter would have to be larger "between corners" than "in the middle of the side").

Comment: relevant link: [Reuleaux polygons](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReuleauxPolygon.html).

Answer (score 8):

Looking at this:

> [CoinBrothers](https://coin-brothers.com/catalog/shape/multangular_polygon)

it is rarely true.

For example, Australia 2019:

> https://coin-brothers.com/catalog/coin3771

Comment: @DrXorile; there's more recent later on

Comment: I wonder how all these machines do in vending machines. Must make it tricky.

Comment: @DrXorile The Australian 50c piece has been around in its current shape since 1969. I understand there are a few vending machines that don't accept it, but I can't recall ever encountering one, and by my understanding the issue is with its size rather than the shape. It's about 32 mm across, much larger than any other Australian coin, so distinguishing it from others isn't a challenge but everything has to be larger to accommodate it.

Answer (score 5):

Note that

> The puzzle was posted on April 1st, a.k.a. April's Fools day

It turns out that

> The post contains several falsehoods.

For example,

> "**An** example" refers to an image with **three** coins. It is [not in fact universally true that all coins are odd-sided](https://coin-brothers.com/search?cat_code=KM&cat_name=Standard+Catalog+of+World+Coins+%28Krause+Publications%29&year-from=2000&era-from=AD&year-to=2019&era-to=AD&coin-type=type1&image-type=All+object+types&sedge-type=All+edge+types&sshape=multangular_polygon) (thanks JonMark Perry).

Indeed,

> This question is not in fact a trivia question, but an Aprils Fools puzzle.

The answer is obviously

> That I'm reading *way* too much into this. Possible ideas: "odd" refers to "odd one out". From the three coins, the larger 50p is no longer in production. The 20p is of a different denomination. The orientation in the picture may not be random. But somehow it should all link back to the coins being (roughly) polygonal...

Comment: Rot13: creuncf pbafvqre gung bqq pna zrna crephyvne be hahfhny.

Comment: Love it. I wish I were that clever...

Comment: @DrXorile Aww man! I really thought there was a "Modern Polygonal Coin™" puzzle in here...